# Unable to get the complete notes/info part of Get-Aduser

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the 'info' property of a list of users using basic command as follow:

```
$users = gc 'C:\Users.txt'

$ADinfo = foreach($userID in $users) 
{ 
    Get-ADUser -Filter "Employeenumber -eq $userID" -Properties * | select info  
}

$adinfo | export-csv C:\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The info property has multiple lines of text but the output contains only the very first line. Not sure what to do to get complete text, preferably first two lines. I tried -first 2, no luck.

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine here. How did you determine that the resulting csv only contains a single line?

Comment: I must clarify, when I run get-aduser $user -properties * shows complete content of 'info'. However, get-aduser $user -properties *  | select info does not, nor does exporting it.

Comment: Again, _how did you determine this_? What does `Get-Content C:\Users.csv` show you?

Comment: Holy mother of god. I just checked, that actually did the trick. get-content .csv shows the data as I need. Now just opened the csv in Excel and enlarged the cell, can see the content there.

Comment: that actually shows all lines, where as I need only first 3. select info -first 3 doesnt work.

Comment: the `info` property contains a _single_ multi-line string, so you'll have to split it up into multiple strings if you want to use `Select -Frist 3`